# Sigma summation to non-general summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

When doing definite integral as the limit of a sum I noticed they had changed Sigma summation to general summation not as general equation.

Here's an example

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} h \sum_{r=1}^n (a+rh)^m$$
$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} h[(a+h)^m+(a+2h)^m +....+ (a+nh)^m]$$
$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{(z+h)^{m+1}-z^{m+1}}{h}$$

How they found 3rd line? Is there any equation to find huge summation? I had heard that $\Sigma$ was used like for loop condition (in programming). But, how they wrote 3rd line? They write different equation all the time (for different functions). So, how to find it? Or, Is there a trick?

[image]

Since, someone was unclear of earlier ones so, I am showing another one.

[image]

Comment: Did $a$ become $z$ in the last line?

Comment: @TomDavis Maybe, Yes! But, I don't have any idea... Maybe, it was a typo in my book

Comment: I don't think the book is saying it's an equality.  I don't know the language, but I would imagine they are saying "to solve this equation, we can use what we know about this equation in $z$".  Then, they show that term by term in the $a$ equation you get $m+1$ and use this to solve the integral of $x^m$.  That's the only thing I can think of, without more context and language skills.

Comment: @TomDavis Beside that 3rd line which I wrote in question, they wrote that `here` then, they put it

Comment: Yes, the sigma is an operator that represents a "general" summation.  You can always write out all the terms explicitly.  The index (in this case $r$) is replaced with the sequence of numbers starting from the min (in this cas $r=1$) to the max (in this case $r=n$).  Do you want help solving these definite integrals, or was the question solely about how the summation operator works?

Comment: @TomDavis See 4th number line (after Sigma summation) in second image. I want to know how they found it?

Comment: Please type out the equation in question. Images are not easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the sum
$$
s = \sum_{n=0}^m r^n,
$$
in explicit form
$$
s = 1 + r + r^2 + r^3 + \cdots + r^m.
$$
Now look at the same sum multiplied by $r$
$$
rs = r + r^2 + r^3 + r^4 +\cdots +r^m+ r^{m+1}
$$
This is *almost* identical to the original sum without the first term
$$
rs = s-1+r^{m+1}
$$
solving for $s$ gives
$$ 
\sum_{n=0}^m r^n = \frac{1-r^{m+1}}{1-r}
$$
as stated in the parentheses in the book.

The definite integral of the exponential function given by the limit of Simpson's rule (area of rectangles where the width goes to zero)
$$
\int_a^b e^x dx = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}h\sum_{r=1}^n e^{a+rh}\\
= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}h\left[e^{a+h} + e^{a+2h} + e^{a+3h} + \cdots + e^{a+nh} \right]\\
= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}he^{a+h}\left[1+e^h+(e^h)^2 + (e^h)^3 + \cdots + e^{(n-1)h}\right] 
$$
is now in a form where the sum above can be used, with $r=e^{h}$ and $m=n-1$
$$
\int_a^b e^x dx = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} he^{a+h}\frac{1-e^{nh}}{1-e^h}
$$
which is the line you are looking for.

The limit needs to be taken with care, because although $h\rightarrow 0$ the product $nh$ stays finite, recall $b-a=nh$.  Therefore the limit is
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} he^{a+h}\frac{1-e^{nh}}{1-e^h}=e^a\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}(1-e^{b-a})\frac{he^h}{1-e^h}\\
=(e^a-e^b)\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{he^h}{1-e^h}.
$$
This limit is in indeterminate form ($0/0$) so use L'Hopital's rule and take the derivative of the numerator and denominator to obtain
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{he^h}{1-e^h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^h + he^h}{-e^h}=-1
$$
and finally
$$
\int_a^b e^x dx = e^b-e^a.
$$